# Canonical way to check if a bit is on in C?

Tags: c, bit

Is there a canonical solution to checking whether a bit in a byte is on, or should I do what I feel like? There's a lot of possible solutions, e.g:

```
value = ( reg & 0x20 ) == 0x20;
value = ( reg & 0b00100000 ) == 0b00100000;
value = ( reg >> 5 ) & 1;
```

**Clarification**: I wasn't asking about more possibilities, but whether there is a canonical solution or not.

Comment: `0b` isn't allowed in the C language... so it about as far from canonical as it gets.

Answer (score 4):

```
value = reg & 0x20
```

is enough in most situations as any non-zero values are evaluated as true in C.

Also note that binary forms like `0b00100000` is not standard C, but an extension in some compilers like gcc.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that 0b wasn't standard.

Comment: While this works, one should be aware that value might be lost if `value` is smaller integer type than the bit has. So you cannot mask `0x8000`  to `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way would be

```
(reg & 0x20u) > 0
```

The `u` at the end of the literal ensures that you don't do a bitwise operation on a signed number (which you will be doing if reg is of type char or short). Bitwise operations and signed numbers shouldn't be mixed.

The `> 0` ensures that you have a result that is essentially boolean type, in the simplest possible way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double 'not' to make assigment safe (`0` or `1` only):

```
value = !!(reg & 0x20); // !! forces any non-zero value to 1
```

If you don't need assignment (usage in `if`, `while`, `for`, ...), then this trick is not necessary as any non-zero will equal `TRUE`-condition:

```
while(reg & 0x20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is just to use bit mask:

```
is5bit_on = reg & 0x20;
```

Note: there is no need in comparing `reg & 0x20` with `0x20` if you check only one bit.

Comment: The == check converts the result to something that is essentially boolean. Which means that you can store the result in a `bool` variable. And the "canonical" way to write control statements such as `if()` is to always treat the condition as boolean, rather than abusing the fact that C can use the int type as a boolean type. So I'd say that `( reg & 0x20 ) == 0x20` is definitely more pure than  `reg & 0x20`, although I'd prefer `> 0` to convert the expression to "essentially boolean".

Comment: What boolean type you are talking about? It's C, not C++, so there is no bool type (except `_Bool` from C99 standard which is used quite rare for compatibility reasons). So `( reg & 0x20 ) == 0x20` is definitely not more pure as it operates with more operands with the same effect.

Comment: What Lundin probably means with pure, is that when the result is always only 0 or 1, it can be safely assigned to any standard type. When using only masking, it is not guaranteed, as masked value might be bigger than size of the variable you are assigning it to.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding magic numbers as much as possible and using C99 booleans, I'd go with

```
enum { SOME_FLAG = 1 << 5 };
_Bool has_some_flag = reg & SOME_FLAG;
```

Comment: @djgandy: of course enums (in particular anonymous ones) are 'for' declaring integer costants; the name `enum` is just a historical accident (same as other keywords like `inline` and `register`) and shouldn't be used to argue semantics or usage